# Build multiple rest APIs like multi module project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, multi-module

I'm working on spring boot project. Requirement is to build multiple rest APIs with one Application class. So the approach followed is, I created kinda multi module project where in parent project have included all rest APIs as modules. Don't want each modules to have App class as it creates separate java instance, but each module have rest controllers and they exposes various methods. Finally i need to export as one jar to host on server.

Project strucutre:

ParentAPI - Contains POM.xml but no main application class. ExecuteAPI, Child1 and Child2 are modules within it

ExecuteAPI  - Contain main aplication class. Passing Child1 and Child2 application classes to SpringApplicationBuilder. Both Child1 and Child2 added as dependency inside POM.xml

Child1  - Has application class and it's own controller etc and POM we well.

Child2  - Has application class and it's own controller etc and POM we well.

Im running ExecuteAPI which runs the corresponding controller from Child1 and Child2. 
Is this valid approach? if no, any better way to do it? Does this creates multiple java instance for each module or just one for ExecuteAPI?

Comment: Show us the file structure and package naming (name spacing) you've used please.

Comment: Hi Casburn, I have added project structure, let me know if you want to see code. Also re-framed my question. thank you.